# Knockoutjs and Form binding

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have the following view and form some reason the following line causes an error that OrderID is not a property of Order. However it definitely is.

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OrderID)</td>
```

Here is the view

```
@model IEnumerable<GeogSocSite.Models.Order>
<head>
<title>Order</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/TableSheet.css">

</head>
<body>
<h1>Choose Your Tickets</h1>
<p> Hello</p>
<form action="@Url.Action("NextPage", "Order")" method="get">

    <table align="center" cellspacing="2" border="1" table data-bind='visible: gifts().length>0'>

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th align="center">Description</th>
                <th align="center">Price</th>
                <th align="center">Add</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach : gifts">

            @foreach (GeogSocSite.Models.Ticket ticket in ViewBag.listTickets)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: ticketID">@Html.DisplayFor(m => ticket.TicketID)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OrderID)</td>
                    <td align="center">@ticket.Description</td>
                    <td align="center">@ticket.Price</td>
                    <td align="center"> @Html.DropDownList("Quantity",  (IList<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Quantities, "", new { data_bind = " value:  selectedOptionValue" }) </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button data-bind='click: addGift'>Add Gift</button>
    <button data-bind='enable: gifts().length > 0' type='submit'>Submit</button>
 </form>
    <div>
        <button data-bind="click: next">Next </button>
    </div>
    <div id="proceed">
        @Html.ActionLink("Proceed", "Order", "Order")
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", "Events")
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var GiftModel = function (gifts) {
            var self = this;
            self.gifts = ko.observableArray(gifts);


            self.save = function (form) {
                alert("Could now transmit to server: " + ko.utils.stringifyJson(self.gifts));
                // To actually transmit to server as a regular form post, write this: ko.utils.postJson($("form")[0], self.gifts);
            };
        };

        var viewModel = new GiftModel([

        ]);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

        // Activate jQuery Validation
        $("form").validate({ submitHandler: viewModel.save });
    </script>
</body>
```

I just want to allow user to select quantities of each ticket type displayed then send this, along with the orderID and TicketID back to the controller on a button click but I'm having real difficulty. Here is my Order Model

```
 public class Order
 {

    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    //foreign key
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Event")]
    public int EventID { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public float OrderTotal { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser user { get; set; }

    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }

    }
```

And here is my controller method

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult CreateOrder(int id)
    {
        //  Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
        //  ticket.EventID = id;
        //  ViewBag.EventID = new SelectList(db.Events, "EventID", "Name");
        //  return View(ticket);
        Event e1 = db.Events.Find(id);
        List<SelectListItem> quantities = new List<SelectListItem>();
        ViewBag.listTickets = (from t in db.Tickets where t.EventID == id select t).ToList();
        if (e1.TicketsAvailable == 0)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        else if (e1.TicketsAvailable < 5)
        {
            for (int loop = 0; loop < e1.TicketsAvailable; loop++)
            {
                quantities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = loop.ToString(), Value = loop.ToString() });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int loop = 0; loop <= 5; loop++)
            {
                quantities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = loop.ToString(), Value = loop.ToString() });
            }
        }
            ViewBag.Quantities = quantities;
            string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            ApplicationUser currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);
            Order order = new Order { EventID = e1.EventID, OrderDate = DateTime.Now, user=currentUser };
            return View();

        }

    }
```

I'm totally stuck on what is probably a simple task to do but as I'm new to asp.net mvc and knockoutjs I'm finding it very difficult to get done. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that your model for your view is an IEnumerable<Order> not Order. You should probably change the model to @model GeogSocSite.Models.Order instead.

Comment: Thank you very much that fixed my build error! Would you have any idea why why OrderID is empty as I thought I was passing a new Order into the View and the ID would be generated automatically? Thanks again for your help @Inari

Comment: In order to pass your model in to your view, you need to supply it as the parameter to the return method.

An example would be

    return View(model);

Comment: that's great that worked thank you! Probably another stupid question but if I wanted to pass all this data to my controller and save this to my database? At the moment the form action and method are get do I need to change this @Inari?

Comment: Take a look at the tutorials on the asp.net website. They will help guide you further in your endeavour. ;)